# Transforming a string DNA in to a Seq object in Biopython

Tags: python, biopython

There are any way that i can transform a user input string in to a byopython Seq object?
I try a lot of things and search in the google but not a answer.
Thanks

Comment: if you include some of the things you've already tried it'll make it far easier for us to help you. as it stands, this question is likely to be closed as too broad

Comment: I try at first seq = Seq(sequence), seq=Seq(input(Enter your seq), ei, but what i didn't try was use the methods in the string itself. What i will do later. For ex sequence.transcribe().

Comment: `from Bio.Seq import Seq: seq=Seq(input('Enter your seq'))` does work

Comment: @Hey Chris_Rands It works great. Thank you for your time. Really appreciate.

Comment: @Paulo insert your comment with code into your question. It makes it more valid than leaving it as comment.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why we need the input(),
for Biopython 1.74 you can do:

```
record = Seq('GATTACA')
```

Please also have a look at [SeqRecord official tutorial](https://biopython.org/wiki/SeqRecord) (section: Creating a SeqRecord object).